# Hive - External table's string values are showing NULL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I have JSON files in S3 bucket. The file structure would be,

```
s3://bucket/myfiles/dt=2019060101/file1.JSON
s3://bucket/myfiles/dt=2019060101/file2.JSON
s3://bucket/myfiles/dt=2019060102/file1.JSON
s3://bucket/myfiles/dt=2019060102/file2.JSON

dt=yyyymmddHH
```

if I create an external table on top of `s3://bucket/myfiles/dt=2019060102/` then Im able to see the data.

But If I create the same table with `PARTITION (dt string)`, then add partitions, Its not working.

```
ALTER TABE my_tbl ADD PARTITION (dt='2019060101') location 's3://bucket/myfiles/dt=20190601/';
```

Im able to see the data which has numeric values even the data type is string. All the columns which has any string values are showing NULL.

Can someone help to solve this issue? 
Im using `EMR (v5.16) and hive 2.3.3`

Comment: please share your create external table command with partition.

Comment: and the sample content of your json file.